# Symbol Server for Microsoft.Extension.DependencyInjection.Abstractions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to debug aspnet-core application to step through `Microsoft.Extension.DependencyInjection.Abstractions`

Can any one help me in locating PDB files from symbol servers.

I have properly configured debugging options to step through .Net Framework code and enabled Microsoft Symbol server. but it look likes pdf files for aspnet-core modules (for e.g. microsoft.extenstion.Dependencyinjection.Abstractions) is not available on Microsoft Symbol Server